# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Panel'

Tags: pandas, panel-data

I am getting an error while I am converting dictionary data frames to Panel dataframe

`panelda = pd.Panel()`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-e8e84d2172b7> in <module>
     11     panaldata[ticker] = panaldata[ticker][["Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"]]
     12     #print(panaldata[ticker].head())
---> 13 panelda = pd.Panel()
     14 #panelda.minor_axis = ["Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"]
     15 #panelda.major_axis = panel.major_axis.tz_localize(pytz.ist)

c:\miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in __getattr__(name)
    242         return _SparseArray
    243 
--> 244     raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
    245 
    246 

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Panel'
```

Comment: Yep, pd.Panel was deprecated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer myself, I was using the latest Pandas v1.2.0, where the panel has been removed from Pandas module 0.25.0 onwards.

```
print(pd.__version__)
print(np.__version__)
1.2.0
1.19.4
```

From [0.25.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html) / [1.2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html) release notes

```
Warning: The panel has been fully removed. For N-D labeled data structures, please use xarray
```

unless you want to use [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/), you need to uninstall and install the version prior to that.

Comment: I encountered this when using xarray=0.11.3 due to needing python3.7. My solution was `conda uninstall pandas` then `conda install -c conda-forge pandas=0.24`. Thanks for your help.